# Cannot use variable of type chan chan int as <-chan <-chan int value

Tags: go, channel

1. **<-chan <-chan int** is return value.
2. I want to assign a **chan chan int** value to it.

How to do that?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but a basic code example would have been helpful. The presence of code usually improves the quality of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> How to do that?

You cannot. You could try returning a `chan <-chan int`.